# Converting Body to HTML Not Working

Tags: html, powershell, html-email

I am trying to make my body of text convert to HTML so it does not show as plain text in my email.

Here is the code

```psh
$From = ""
$To = ""
$SMTPServer = ""
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = ""
$Password = ""
$subject = "Test Powershell"
$body = $htmlreport
$bodyAsHtml = $true
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body);
```

I cant see to get the report to send as HTML.

Comment: There is not enough information here, you've not included the text you're trying to convert, you've not shown what `$htmlreport` contains. Also, creating a variable called `$bodyAsHtml` and setting it to true will do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the individual strings to `$smtp.Send()`, you should create a [`MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) object and send that instead:

```powershell
$msg            = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.From       = $From
$msg.To         = $To
$msg.Subject    = $subject
$msg.Body       = $body
$msg.IsBodyHtml = $true # this is where the magic happens

$smtp             = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort)
$smtp.EnableSSL   = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)

$smtp.Send($msg) # and then send the message we just composed above
```

Answer (score 1):

`$bodyAs` contains `` `enter code here` ``. You should **remove** that. You also don't set it anywhere.

Maybe try the [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) cmdlet instead:

```powershell
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -To $To -From $From -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: The \`enter code here\` was probably inserted by mistake by pressing <Ctrl>+<K> or clicking the `{}` icon in the edit textbox.